# Sufficient condition for local martingale property of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, localization, martingales

Is the following correct and/or a (simple) known result?

Let $X$ be a local martingale and $H$ an integrand for $X$, such that the stochastic integral $\int H\cdot dX\ge x$  for some random variable. Then $\int H\cdot dX$ is also a local martingale.

---

I would prove it in analogy to the proof in Corollaire 3.5 of [this paper](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1994__30_2_303_0.pdf):

Define the process $V_t=\int^t_0 H\cdot dX-x\ge 0$ and the sequence of stopping times $T_n=\inf\{t:V_t\ge n\}$. Thus, $(V^{T_n})_{t-}\le n$ which together with $V_t\ge 0$ yields $\Delta V^{T_n}=\Delta\left(\int H\cdot d(X^{T_n})\right)\ge -n$. The assertion then follows from Proposition 3.3 of the same paper.

---

Proposition 3.3: The stochastic integral $\int H\cdot dX$ is a local martingale if and only if there exists a sequence of stopping times with limit $\infty$ and a series of integrable negative random variables $\theta_n$, such that $ H\cdot\Delta X^{T_n}\ge\theta_n$.

Comment: Hi as soon as H is locally integrable, the stochastic integral $int H\cdot dX$ makes sense is a local martingale itself http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/preservation-of-the-local-martingale-property/

Comment: @TheBridge How can I see that H is locally integrable? Which theorem/corollary of your link are you referring to?

Comment: @TheBridge and upvoters of his comment. Could you provide more insight? Thanks!